# Loading large number of static files in Web App not performing well

Tags: azure

We are building a web app that needs to load a large amount of small files (but well below 5MB in total size) containing layout templates to handle browser request in a CMS system. On-premises this works fine but after migrating the site to Azure loading the files, from Azure blob storage, takes too much time 4x compared to on-premises deployments.

Comment: azure cdn is an option. if not already do check this post http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingVideoMovingMyWebsitesImagesToTheAzureCDNAndUsingACustomDomain.aspx

Comment: Actually there's no question here, just a statement. Also, we have zero knowledge of how you deployed it to Azure (VM? Cloud Service? Web app?) and we have no idea what performance tier you used on-premises vs in Azure. In any case, it's not a programming question and will likely be closed as *unclear what you're asking*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure blob storage in general is quite performant especially for larger files because then there is a good balance between overhead in calling a REST service (like Blob storage) and the throughput can be up to 60 mb/s.

In your case it seems that loading too many small files disrupts this balance. A solution could be, assuming the files are static, to add these files to the website deployment itself (including them in the project and making sure they get deployed). This will accelerate reading the files substantially.

You can try to further optimize this by also loading the files in Redis Cache and fall back to reading the files from the website deployment.